# Subordinate norm is equal to $\Vert A\Vert_M=\Vert MAM^{-1}\Vert$ for the norm $\Vert x\Vert_M=\Vert Mx\Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $M\in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{K})$ a nonsingular matrix, we have $\Vert x\Vert_M=\Vert Mx\Vert$ is a norm over $\Bbb{K}^n$. I have to prove that the subordinate norm is equal to $\Vert A\Vert_M=\Vert MAM^{-1}\Vert$.

I know we have $\Vert MA\Vert\le \Vert M\Vert\Vert A\Vert$ and also $\Vert AM^{-1}\Vert\le \Vert A\Vert\Vert M^{-1}\Vert$ then $$\Vert MAM^{-1}\Vert\le \Vert M\Vert\Vert A\Vert\Vert\Vert M^{-1}\Vert$$

How can I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\|A\|_{M} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_M}{\|x\|_M} $$ $$= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|MAx\|}{\|Mx\|} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|MAM^{-1}Mx\|}{\|Mx\|}$$

Does this spark some ideas?

---

Turns out there is slightly simple way to prove this.
$$\|A\|_{M} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_M}{\|x\|_M} $$ $$= \sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0} \frac{\|MAx\|}{\|Mx\|} = \sup_{y \in \mathbb{K}^n, y \neq 0} \frac{\|MAM^{-1}y\|}{\|MM^{-1}y\|} = \|MAM^{-1}\|$$

Comment: We have $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{K}^n, x \neq 0}\frac{\|MAM^{-1}Mx\|}{\|Mx\|}\le ||MAM^{-1}||$ and I have to choose a good $x$ to prove that the supremum is reached?

Comment: Yeap. That is what at least I have in my mind.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a simpler approach, which avoids finding a good x.

Comment: I don't understand your equality, you cannot choose $x=M^{-1}y$ so why we have equality on the second line?

Comment: We are not choosing $x = M^{-1}y$. Remember that M is non-singular, therefore, $x \to Mx$ is a bijection.

Comment: Oh good Idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a difference between the way and "the slightly simple way"? It looks exactly the same.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel In the first approach, we can show that the $\|MAM^{-1}\|$ is an upper bound to the subordinate norm and then attempt to find an $x$ that realizes this upper bound thereby proving the equality. In the second approach, one doesn't have to find such an x. The equality follows from the definition of the subordinate norm itself.

Comment: If you like. Although the "first approach" obviously is identical to the first few $=$'s of the "second approach".

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Sure. Since I suggested a slightly different approach to the OP earlier, I decided to mark the two approaches separately, so as to not obfuscate anything. Although, it might have been a tad bit unnecessary.